# C# Web application finding the radius from given postcode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications

I want to add a feature in my web application where the user inputs their postcode. If the postcode is in a mile radius from the fixed postcode where the GPs is located, then only the user can register, otherwise they can't. 
What do I need to add this feature?

Answer (score 1):

To this you will first need to get Latitude/Longitude for both the postal codes. For this you can make use of Google Maps GeoLocation API ([Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?csw=1)).

Now, you can find the distance between these two Latitude/Longitude combinations using Great-circle distance ([Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)).